# Disambiguation warning when running application

Tags: qt, windows-vista, disambiguation

I am developing a Qt application, and I've been asking some friends of mine to test it. One of them told me that he can't run the application. Here is the error he gets:

[image: Disambiguation Error Image]

When he presses yes, then he gets a "mingwm10.dll was not found" message. Of course there is mingwm10.dll in the working directory and then it says "application stopped working" error. When he presses no, it opens PeaZip.

I've tested the application successfully on Windows XP, Windows 7 and Windows Vista, so I really have no idea what's going on. (However, my friend is using Windows Vista, if that's helpful)

So, do you have any idea what it means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From PeaZip's [user manual (PDF)](http://www.peazip.org/peazip_help.pdf):

> If a single archive file is dragged to the browser PeaZip will show a
>   disambiguation popup to ask if adding the object to the archive or
>   rather opening it.

So if I have to guess he is either not putting the executable and other files into a clean directory, but into an archive, or directly trying to run the application from the archive. Have you by any chance wrapped everything into a single zip file which you gave him?

Make sure everything gets put into a clean directory and try running the exe from there.

Comment: Thanks, the problem was that user was trying to run application directly from the rar archive without extracting it.